# GWT Maps Icon.NewInstance intermittently throwing exception

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

I'm creating a custom icon to use as a marker on a map, and intermittently, but quite often this function:

```
private Icon createIcon(String Url) {
    Icon icon = Icon.newInstance(Url);  //<-- This line throws exception        
    icon.setIconSize(Size.newInstance(30, 30));
    icon.setIconAnchor(Point.newInstance(6, 20));
    icon.setInfoWindowAnchor(Point.newInstance(14, 4));
    return icon;
}
```

throws this exception:

```
11:05:55.076 [ERROR] [simplemap] Uncaught exception escaped

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(311), JavaScript object(310), JavaScript object(333)]): undefined is not a function
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anybody have any insight as to why this happens and what I can do to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a concurrency issue where the map was not finished loading when the icons were trying to be generated.  When I moved some code around so it only ran after the Maps asynchronous load was finished this issue went away.